# Manipular Cache com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá

Eu preciso trabalhar com o cache de todos os navegadores, eu preciso guardar dados no cache e depois fazer a leitura utilizando  Jquery. Alguém conhece algum site com tutorial sobre o assunto ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o **localStorage**

O **localStorage** salva dados no computador do visitante, que ficam vinculados ao (e apenas acessíveis pelo) seu domínio. E pra usar é bem simples:

```
// Cria um item "usuario" com valor "Usuário 1"
window.localStorage.setItem('usuario', 'Usuário 1');

// Depois, em outra página ou aba, recupera esse item
var usuario = window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');

// Remove o item
window.localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
```

Usando o **sessionStorage**

Já o **sessionStorage** faz exatamente a mesma coisa, só que os dados ficam salvos apenas durante a sessão (e são apagados quando o visitante fecha a aba/navegador):

```
// Cria um item "usuario" com valor "Usuário 1"
window.sessionStorage.setItem('usuario', 'Usuário 1');

// Depois, em outra página ou aba, recupera esse item
var usuario = window.sessionStorage.getItem('usuario');

// Remove o item
window.sessionStorage.removeItem('usuario');
```

Comment: Incrivel, Obrigado amigo.